# Adding polygons to a scene with from an arraylist

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to add a new polygon to an existing scene, but it doesn't appear. is this a problem with the triangle not being visible or is it not being added to the scene.

```java
if (enemyPoints == 5) {
 enemyPoints = enemyPoints - 5;
 triangles.add(new Polygon(30, 10, 54));
 System.out.println("triangle made");
 triangles.get(k).setFill(Color.RED);
 triangles.get(k).setLayoutX(5);
 triangles.get(k).setLayoutY(5);
 root.getChildren().add(triangles.get(k));
 k++;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not very clear, we are not sure for k value and if enemyPoints == 5  then instead of doing enemyPoints = enemyPoints-5; you can do enemyPoints = 0;

Comment: k is just the number for the newly created polygon.

Comment: I am wondering what just 3 double values in the Polygon constructor mean. They should be pairwise x,y coordinates.

Comment: More precisely you'd use `new Polygon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)` to create a triangle.